# Download a file in C++ (without external libraries)

Tags: c++, download

It is possible to download a file from an URL with C++ WITHOUT ADDING external resources, like libCURL? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you can code the whole network code yourslf, yes. You can also copy the lib code in your main.cpp, that will work too... (but that's bad).

Comment: It depends. Would you describe `socket()` `connect()`, `read()`, and `write()` as external libraries?

Comment: No, it is not. If you can drop the silly requirements, you can get it done.

Comment: Does the operating system API count as an external resource?

Comment: In 100% pure C++, no, it is not possible. At the very least, you have to use operating system calls.

Comment: @Cornstalks: in *portable* C++ it's not possible. Back in the MS-DOS days, I wrote code that worked directly with a network adapter to do it without an OS assistance either though. Of course, that wouldn't work with a modern OS, but who needs such frippery?

Comment: Ok thanks! I will use libCURL, no time to code the whole stuff :P

Comment: IF you're on Windows use WinInet.

Answer (score 3):

It sure is.  But it takes a lot of time.

BTW, why don't you want to use libCURL.

Comment: No, I haven't said that :P I was only wondering about other methods...

Answer (score 2):

Sure, because libCURL is written. What you need is to implement it yourself. Check socket programming for that.

Comment: libCURL still uses things external to C++, namely OS APIs.

Answer (score 2):

If you read the C++ standard, there is no standard library for networking as of today. There are however plans to include such a library in future versions of the C++ standard.

SG4 (Study Group responsible for networking library) has recently set up a [wiki on Github](https://github.com/SG4/draft/wiki)